# Turn series into sum

Tags: summation, power-series

I have two series that Im suppose to turn into sum and im having reallu much trouble doing that i just cant figure it out so it would be really amazing if anyone could help me a little bit. The series are

$$A=  c_0(x^{1/3}-\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}+\frac{1}{10}x^{7/3}-\frac{1}{150}x^{10/3}+...)$$

$$B=c_0(1-x+\frac{1}{5}x^2-\frac{1}{60}x^3+...)$$

I tried it and what I have come up with is this but Im stuck here and i dont even know if its the right way or not 
for A $$ c_n=(-1)^n*\frac{1}{k!(3k-1)} *c_0 $$ 
but there is something not working with this thing and i cant find how to make it right and same for my other solution

for B $$c_n= (-1)^n*\frac{1}{k!(2k-1} *c_0$$

If anyone has any idea how to get the sum right it would be amazing thanks.

Comment: what is the term after $- \frac{x^{10/3}}{150}$?. The exponent of $x$ is easy $n - \frac{2}{3} $. But the relation between the coefficient of $x$ and the term number is not clear

Comment: As Ameryr commented, have you other terms ? Where do the expansions come from ?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about integer sequences, check the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A086619). For the particular sequence 1, 2, 10, 150, that link is the only matching sequence, which I don't think is what you want to use. Did you copy your question correctly?

If you did, and the problem just wants you to find any sum that works for the terms they give you, then you could always try...

$$
n = \frac{3k+1}{3} \\
A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^n \\
c_k = (-1)^k \frac{1}{f(k)} c_0
$$

Now let's try to figure out what to put for $f(k)$. We want $f(0) = 1$, $f(1) = 2$, $f(2) = 10$, and $f(3) = 150$, and there's four points, so we can fit it to a cubic function:

$$
f(k) = ak^3 + bk^2 + ck^1 + dk^0 \\
f(0) = 1 = d \\
f(1) = 2 = a + b + c + d \\
f(2) = 10 = 8a + 4b + 2c + d \\
f(3) = 150 = 27a + 9b + 3c + d
$$

So we're left with three equations in three unknowns, since we know that $d = 1$. Let's solve it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= 2 - b - c - d = 1 - b - c \\
4b &= 10 - 8a - 2c - d = 10 - 8(1 - b - c) - 2c - 1 \\
&= 1 + 8b + 6c \\
b &= -\frac{1+6c}{4} \\
3c &= 150 - 27a - 9b - d = 150 - 27\left(1 - \left(-\frac{1+6c}{4}\right) - c\right) - 9\left(-\frac{1+6c}{4}\right) - 1 \\
&= 235/2 \\
c &= 235/6 \\
b &= -\frac{1+6(235/6)}{4} = -59 \\
a &= 1 - (-59) - 235/6 = 125/6
\end{aligned}
$$

Now finally, we have the coefficients,

$$
c_k = (-1)^k \frac{1}{\frac{125}{6}k^3 - 59k^2 + \frac{235}{6}k + 1} c_0
$$

I'll leave the second problem as an exercise. Just follow the same method and you'll eventually find a polynomial which works. Good luck!